# Parsing function arguments based on pattern

Tags: python

I'm completely stumped as to how to do this. I've been trying for a while, but can't find a suitable way.

So, let's say that I have a pattern representing a function with two arguments: `function_name(arg0, arg1)`.

How can I get the values of `arg0` and `arg1`?

Sample input would look like `function_name(10, 20), function_name(function_name(15 + 2, 16), 6)` and such.

Another pattern would be `function_2[arg0](arg1)`.

So basically, how can I find strings that match this sort of pattern and extract the values of the arguments?

Answer (score 1):

you can use module `re` for regex pattern matching:

```
In [27]: import re
    ...: s='function_name(10, 20)'
    ...: m=re.search(r'\((.*),(.*)\)', s)
    ...: m.groups()
Out[27]: ('10', ' 20')

In [28]: arg1, arg2 = m.groups()
    ...: print arg1, arg2
    ...: 
10  20
```